# what is angularjs and MVC framework?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, frameworks

"what is angular and mvc? than how works **Angular** **JS** with **MVC** frameworks"

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a java script framework and it used to single page application for ex: (face like function and command).

In AngularJS the MVC pattern is implemented in JavaScript and HTML. The view is defined in HTML, while the model and controller are implemented in JavaScript. There are several ways that these components can be put together in AngularJS but the simplest form starts with the view.